# How to set formatting to have one tag per line in Visual Studio XML editor?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xaml, format

I want to be able to format XML so that every tag is fully laid on one single line, so for example when pressing "format current document/selection" going from this:

```
 <A>
    <B Property="x"
    Value="1" />
 </A>
```

to this:

```
<A>
    <B Property="x" Value="1" />
</A>
```

I did not find anything in the settings or even on forums, maybe there is an extension for this ? Thanks for any input

EDIT: I mean having having the "<" and ">" of a tag on the same line, no matter what.

Comment: Are you talking about Visual Studio Code? Or are you talking about the Visual Studio IDE?

Comment: I'm talking about the Visual Studio IDE. I am using Visual Studio 2022 Community edition.

Comment: I don't think you actually mean "one tag per line": for example `<a>thing</a>` has the start tag and end tag on the same line.

Comment: @MichaelKay you are right my bad, I meant having the  opening "<" and  closing ">" of every tags on the same line.